# Item becomes null after submitting page in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I'm currently using Oracle APEX. I have this validation that executes error message whenever an item is null. And I have created a dynamic action when losing focus, it formats into a currency format.

I have this problem whenever I submit the page, my item becomes null / my validation executes.

My assumption is that validation comes first before the dynamic action.

**Validation**

- Item is not null

**Dynamic Action**

- Lose Focus

**Action**

- Execute PLSQL that formats to a currency value.

**Scenario:**

- Fills-up an item
- Click submit button ahead

**Expected Result:**

- Empty validation should not trigger when page is submitted.

**Actual Result:**

- Empty validation is triggering when page is submitted.

Comment: Validations are only executed when the page is submitted (that is why they are in the "processing" section). It is is unclear exactly what you are doing / what is happening. You could create a workspace on apex.oracle.com with a small app showing just you issue and share the credentials. That way someone on this forum can have a look.

Comment: Do you need a dynamic action to format the currency ? It is possible to set a format mask on the page item and then that should happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this set you offending validation to never and make sure the dynamic action is doing what you want. Oracle in general is klugy with number formatting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).